# app bar scrolling with fragment container i need make it fixed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

app bar scrolling up when an edit text in fragment focused and when focus out app bar return to default location image describe when edit text focused any one have this problem before and how to solve it

app_bar_main

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_primary_1"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbar_style"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/frame2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just this line " android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" " removed from the activity in the manifest just remove it solve the problem